# Check if user is blocking 3rd party domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, client-side, blocking

I have run into an issue where a lot of our support calls are about our images not loading because the user is blocking amazon s3 or a similar 3rd party service.  I use 3rd party services for hosting images, video, and some javascript.  Is there a way to detect through javascript if a client is blocking a domain so that we display a message instead of having the user contact support?

```
$.ajax 'http://aws.amazon.com/s3/',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'html'
  complete: (e, xhr, settings) ->
    if e.status == 200
      console.log "Not Blocking S3"
    else
      console.log "Blocking S3"
```

Based on the comments I made an attempt at it, but it is still not working.  It returns blocking when I have no blocks.

The above example coffeescript code does not work as I believe a security error occurs because it is doing an ajax on a different domain.  Firebug shows the request in red, but  says 200.  e.status is returning 0.

Comment: Try and load a resource from that third-party, using JavaScript, and, if it can't be retrieved, give the message?

Comment: I think @DavidThomas means that you should use javascript to do the detection and report the result back to your webserver.

Comment: @jonnyGold: I did indeed; clarified the original comment. =)

Comment: Does not seem to work. Edited original post.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994419/jquery-to-check-image-exists-if-head-404-than-hide-it#answer-12994474) SO answer is also applicable, and it worked better for my purposes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Load an image from the domain you want to check against.

```
<img id="checkImg" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.pngAAA" />
```

​
Just a regular image tag (notice the `AAA` at the end to make it **not** work). Then you can check the width of the image to see if it loaded or not.

```
if(document.getElementById('checkImg').clientWidth != 275)
    alert("Error")
```

The Google logo is 275px wide but the error image (in Chrome at least) is only 18px. So if the image is not 275px wide, I know it did not load.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FFRyE/)

Comment: +1 - This way you don't get cross domain access issues that you would get in Javascript trying to load external resources